# Highcharts chart event load not working for wordcloud

Tags: jquery, highcharts

I am building a project with highcharts however I am facing an issue with load event in word cloud which never gets fired/registered when the wordcloud loads. Here is an example of JSfiddle.

```
var lines = text.split(/[,\. ]+/g),
data = Highcharts.reduce(lines, function (arr, word) {
        var obj = Highcharts.find(arr, function (obj) {
        return obj.name === word;
    });
    if (obj) {
        obj.weight += 1;
    } else {
        obj = {
            name: word,
            weight: 1
        };
        arr.push(obj);
    }
    return arr;
}, []);
console.log(data);
console.log(lines);

Highcharts.chart('container', {
series: [{
    type: 'wordcloud',
    data: data,
    name: 'Occurrences'
}],
title: {
    text: 'Wordcloud of Lorem Ipsum'
},
events: {
load: function () {
    alert("hello");
}
}});
```

Here is the link for Jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/2oq4njb3/10/
So the alert never gets fired when the wordcloud loads

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There isn't an events object at the root level, it's in the chart object.  https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/chart.events

```
Highcharts.chart('container', {
  series: [{
    type: 'wordcloud',
    data: data,
    name: 'Occurrences'
  }],
  title: {
    text: 'Wordcloud of Lorem Ipsum'
  },
  chart: {
    events: {
      load: function() {
        alert("hello");
      }
    }
  },
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/2oq4njb3/13/